# PHP Function Rename Permission denied

Tags: php, permissions, rename

In server, script create new folder, set chmod to 0777, but then it tryes to move files to that folder i get error: Permission denied.

```
mkdir("../".$new_1, 0777);
chmod("../".$new_1, 0777);

mkdir("../".$new_1."/".$new_2, 0777);
chmod("../".$new_1."/".$new_2, 0777);

rename("files/".$failai[$i].".jpg", "../".$new_1.'/'.$new_2."/".$failai[$i].".jpg");
```

> Warning: rename(files/new_file.jpg,../112a/112b/Tech_diz_1.jpg) [function.rename]: Permission denied in ..code/Jpg&Html.php on line 82

Any solutions?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

you'll need to have read and write permissions in the source folder, too.

only having permissions for the target-folder isn't enough as the file is removed from it's source.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the write access to the file? If not, make sure you `chmod` the file to `777` or at least to `644`.

Also, check the existence of the file by giving a `file_exists()` on the file name before you rename. :)

Also, after moving file, you might need to set the permissions using `chmod()` to make it available for renaming. You can do it this way:

```
<?php
    chmod($uploadedFile, 0755);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also have permission to change the file `"files/".$failai[$i].".jpg"`. I would guess that that is going wrong