# PHP rename() - permission denied

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP Function Rename Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11773708/php-function-rename-permission-denied)

I upload a file and change it's permissions to 0777. A fileperms() tells me "33279" which should be equal to 0777.

Why do I still get a "permissions denied" warning? Is it a file owner issue? I could use chown() to fix that have no idea who the owner should be.

```
rename(/Users/stefan/Sites/bla/Rachel.png,banner.png) [function.rename]: Permission denied
```

Not sure how to debug this further.

EDIT: why the downvote?

Comment: You need write permission on the directory, not the file. (You're not changing the file contents, you're changing "directory contents", as it were)

Comment: *"Why the downvote"* - Not me but this could be why http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=PHP+rename%28%29+-+permission+denied

Answer (score 7):

If your code looks like

```
rename('/Users/stefan/Sites/blah/Rachel.png', 'banner.png')
```

**AND** your current working directory is **NOT** that `.../blah` directory, you're trying to rename **AND** move the file into whatever your script's current directory actually is. It'll be that directory that you don't have write permissions on, causing the perm. denied error.

Changing to

```
rename('/Users/stefan/Sites/blah/Rachel.png', '/Users/stefan/Sites/blah/banner.png');
```

would solve the problem, or

```
chdir('/Users/stefan/Sites/blah');
rename('Rachel.phg', 'banner.png');
```